# Track upload Progress AJAX+PHP S3 SDK

Tags: aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a folder into S3 form my local apache server using PHP sdk for S3.

```
// // Create a transfer object.
$manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($client, $source, $dest);
$manager->transfer();
```

this code is called from JS file via ajax.

Is there any way to know the upload progress in the javascript.